# How to get the row id when double click on a row in Keno Grid?

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I have have created a table using traditional HTML way. Then initialized it using the following:

```
$("#MyTable").kendoGrid({
    height: 1200,
    filterable: true,
    groupable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        pageSize: 1000,
        buttonCount: 5
    }
});
```

and registered the double click event with the following:

```
$("#myTable").delegate("tbody>tr", "dblclick", function(e){

    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    alert("id="+id);

});
```

However, when I double-click on a row which has the id attribute, the id comes out `undefined`. I have this working without kendo but I would like to know how I can resolve this so that I may be able to use kendo Grid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It does not have id attribute in html, you need to get it from kendo grid items by getting grid Item for selected row:

```
    $("#grid tbody").on("dblclick", "tr", function(e) {
      var rowElement = this;
      var row = $(rowElement);
      var grid = $("#grid").getKendoGrid();
      var item = grid.dataItem(row);

      alert(item.OrderID)

    });
```

Full example of modified official example:
[Get id on double click](https://dojo.telerik.com/uVIceNat)